# Allow seeing which posts were affected by removed users

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-accounts

When the reputation changes you can see what specific post caused the change, the exception to this rule (are there others?) is when a user is removed.

When I see that my reputation has changed due to the removal of a user I would like to see a list of posts which the user has voted on and how the reputation has changed for each.

Why do I want this? Probably because I'm slightly obsessive, I'm not sure this feature actually has any real value. I would totally understand rejecting the request but I just thought I'd let my wishes known...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a high-reputation user is deleted, it is usually pretty easy to find out who the user was. Users notice that a user is suddenly not in the list of users anymore, or they see a specific post whose owner they know suddenly without an owner. While it is not published explicitly, the identity of the deleted user is often known.

This makes is rather problematic to list the post affected by the deletion as it would give you a list of posts that this specific user voted on. Votes are anonymous, and the deletion is not a good reason to revoke that anonymity.